# How to patch requests.get from a different file in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, patch

I have 2 python files: 1 for unit testing (tests.py) and 1 for the script I want to test (main.py):

```
# In main.py:

import requests

def get_response(url):
    response = requests.get(url);
    # Do stuff...
    return response
```

-

```
# In tests.py

from unittest import mock
from unittest.mock import patch
from my_project.main import get_response

def some_handler(url):
    return "test_response"

class GetResponseTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):

        # setup mocks
        patch('requests.get', mock.Mock(side_effect=some_handler)

    def run_test(self):

        result = get_response("test_response")
```

I want to patch `requests.get` to return `test_response` but the patching is not working because it tries to send a request/make a connection to the url supplied. I think the patch name `requests.get` is not targeting the place it is being used in main.py (as it is referring to where it is defined instead) as some people have mentioned online. But in this scenario I am not sure how to fix this.

If `import requests` is being used in main.py then how can I patch it from another file? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that I need to add `.start()` at the end of the call to creating the patch:

```
# setup mocks
patch('requests.get', mock.Mock(side_effect=some_handler).start()
```

If there are any issues with this solution, or a better way for handling this, I would love to hear it!

Comment: I believe you need to close the paren for `patch(` - I assume the `.start` is called on that rather than the Mock.

Answer (score 1):

1. Mock **get_reponse** instead of mocking **requests.get**(mocking in-built functions;whi le being possible in python is not needed for such a simple usecase).
2. Set return value of **mocked get_response** function to **"test_response"**.

## In tests.py

```
from unittest import mock

class GetResponseTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch("my_project.main.get_response") ##mocking get_response
    def run_test(self, mocked_get_response):
        mocked_get_response.return_value = "test_response" ## setting return value
```